# Intellij is not using settings in MAVEN_OPTS environment variable to build the project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, environment-variables

Experienced on:
`Mac OS monterey 12.0.1`
`IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Ultimate Edition)`

Intellij Idea does not apply the settings available in $MAVEN_OPTS to project builds.

I will post also my workaround. Maybe it will be useful for the others as I could not find the solution in web while searching.

Answer (score 6):

Open IDE `Preferences`,

Then go to `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Maven` -> `Runner`.

There is a `VM Options` input box. You can put your settings there.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+S to open preferences/settings

Comment: Recently I have noticed also this feature as well (in addition to the solution mentioned in the answer): 

Same settings page as mentioned in the answer: `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Maven` -> `Runner`.

Click on the three-bars-icon inside the `Environment variables` text-box, then check the `Include system environment variables` checkbox.

Am not sure from witch version is this feature available. Im on "IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4 (Ultimate Edition)" now.